# Why didn't the dialog in the class execute?

Tags: qt, qt4.7

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->addButton , SIGNAL(clicked()) , this , SLOT(addItem()));
    connect(ui->editButton , SIGNAL(clicked()) , this , SLOT(editItem()));
    connect(ui->deleteButton , SIGNAL(clicked()) , this , SLOT(deleteItem()));
}

void Dialog::addItem()
{
    EditDialog dlg(this);
    dlg.show();

    if(dlg.exec() == EditDialog::Accepted)
    {
        ui->list->addItem(dlg.name() + "--" + dlg.number());
    }
}
```

That a class Dialog to Add Items.
When I run the program and click the Button to execute the Dialog it doesn't do anything so What is the solution?

Comment: Your title should be a short statement of your question, not of your desire to see it answered.

Comment: `@chaos legion`: Click the "edit" link and type in the title field.

Comment: Have you tried just calling `exec()` instead of `show()`?

Comment: Did you declare `addItem` as a slot, and did you use the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the `Dialog` class ?

Comment: ya i declare additem as a slot and i use the Q_OBJECT in the header

Comment: i don't want to use exec() or show() i want to do that code correct thanx for everyone for help my

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use QDialog::Accepted

If you look at [the docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdialog.html#exec) for `QDialog::exec`, you will see that it returns a value from the `QDialog::DialogCode` enum - the values for which are `QDialog::Accepted` and `QDialog::Rejected`.